# Completing the proof using the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is abelian; $H=${$g\in G,|g| \text { divides } 12$}. Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

My idea:  if the order of $g$ divides 12, then the order of the group $G$ must be some multiple of $12$. How can I use the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups to finish this proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just check the definition of a subgroup: closure under multiplication follows from $G$ being abelian, the identity is clearly in $H$, and also an element has the same order as its inverse.

Comment: What is "fundamentai theorem of cyclic groups" for you?

Comment: Your conclusion that $|G|$ should be a multiple of $12$ is incorrect. For example, $G=\{e,g\}$. This satisfies all the conditions. but $|G|=2$.

Comment: what does then the order of $g$ dividing 12 imply? @AnuragA

Comment: @JennieDurham it is just a condition given to deal with specific elements of $G$. In my example, your $H=G$.

Comment: @user281392 how do we know that the inverse of the element has the same order?

Comment: If $a^n=1$ if and only if $(a^n)^{-1}=1$ if and only if $(a^{-1})^n=1$. @JennieDurham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realizing that $H=\{g\in G : g^{12}=e\}$ simplifies everything because it avoids having to worry about orders.

If you can use homomorphisms, then $H$ is a subgroup because $H=\ker \phi$, where $\phi(x)=x^{12}$, which is a homomorphism $G\to G$ because $G$ is abelian.

Otherwise, it is easy to very directly that $H$ is a subgroup using the characterization above. Again, the key point is that $G$ is abelian. Indeed:

- $e\in H$ because $e^{12} = e$.
- If $h \in H$, then $(h^{-1})^{12} = (h^{12})^{-1} = e^{-1} =e $ and so $h^{-1} \in H$.
- If $g,h \in H$, then $(gh)^{12}=g^{12} h^{12} = e e = e $ and so $gh \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- $|e|=1$ divides $12$ so $e \in H$.
- Let $a,b \in H$ and let $|a|=m$ and $|b|=n$. Then both $m,n$ divide $12$. Now consider the element $ab$.

First of all we know that (since $G$ is abelian) $(ab)^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}=e$. Thus $ab$ has a finite order.

Let $|ab|=k$ then $k$ divides $\text{lcm}(m,n)$. But $\text{lcm}(m,n)$ divides $12$ (common multiple of $m$ and $n$). Therefore $k$ divides $12$ as well. This shows closure.

Now complete the inverse property.